# Is it possible to set a FK with different DbContext in Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I've been trying to split my database entities into several DbContext in Entity Framework Code First. However, I need to set an one to many relationship for two tables which are defined in different DbContext. 
I get the following error when I try to execute the enable-migrations command:
[image]

[image]

Are there any way to handle this situation or it is the limitation in entity framework?

As a note that, the TestTable which is covered by the error message is not a member of SKContext. It belong to another DbContext.

Comment: Try to avoid the creation of `TestTable` using `modelBuilder.Ignore<TestTable>();`

Comment: No I haven't tried it. I know how to do that. I will try it but could you please send me some extra clarifications.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I posted the comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid the creation of TestTable using `modelBuilder.Ignore<TestTable>();`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:
modelBuilder.Ignore();
as Fabio Luz said.
Thanks to him